# Angular 5: Pass ng-template down to child component using ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a re-useable component that can take custom templates to render data, while composing the business logic so I don't have to repeat myself.

**Example use case**: a paginated list. The pagination logic should be in the re-useable component so it's only written once, but the themeing/presentation of the data should be customizeable using `ng-template`'s.

I am using `ngTemplateOutlet` in the child component to reference the `ng-template` in the parent, but I am getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function

The first `ng-container` in the re-useable component works fine, it's the last 3 that are giving the error.

This is my re-useable component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'reuseable-component',
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef;
}

<ng-container *ngIf="...">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" 
                 [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: result}">
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="..." [ngTemplateOutlet]="loading"></ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="..." [ngTemplateOutlet]="loadingMore"></ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="..." [ngTemplateOutlet]="noResults"></ng-container>
```

This is the usage:

```
<reuseable-component>
    <ng-template let-result>
        // I have access to 'result' variable here, works fine.
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #loading>
        // This gives the error above
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #loadingMore>
        // This gives the error above
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #noResults>
        // This gives the error above
    </ng-template>
</reuseable-component>
```

How can I fix the last 3 `ng-container` lines in the re-useable component so they render the `ng-template`'s in my usage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved this with a little help from [this article](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e).

Added more `@ContentChild`'s in the re-useable component, and changed the `ngTemplateOutlet`'s to reference the content childs.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'reuseable-component',
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef;
  @ContentChild('loading') loadingRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('loadingMore') loadingMoreRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('noResults') noResultsRef: TemplateRef<any>; 
}

<ng-container *ngIf="...">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" 
                 [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: result}">
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="...">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="loadingRef"></ng-template>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="...">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="loadingMoreRef"></ng-template>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="...">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="noResultsRef"></ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

The logic in the parent component didn't need to change.

Comment: @Simon No clue, probably too little explanation. The solution worked then and still works for me.

Comment: Isn't the [ngTemplateOutlet] supposed to be on ng-containers? (that reference templates)

Comment: @Raid Unless there has been some recent updates in 6.0+, no. That is how it was in old versions of Angular, I believe. From like 4.4-5.0+ up until 6.0 (exclusive of 6.0), `ng-template` would be the right directive to use.

Comment: @Lansana Okay just checking, because in this doc: https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet all the ngTemplateOutlet are on ng-container .. But nothing stops a person from having an outlet on a template I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

ADD THE FOLLOWING IN THE COMPONENT TO BE RE-USED

In the '.HTML' file:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet] = "yourNameReference"
[ngTemplateOutletContext] = "{$ implicit: {name: 'Arthur', lastName: 'Lemos'}">
</ng-container>
```

- [NgTemplateOutletContext] data will be sent to the parent component. Remembering that '$ implicit' can receive any data you want to send to the FATHER component

In the '.ts' file OF THE REUSABLE COMPONENT add the following code WITHIN YOUR CLASS

```
@ContentChild ('yourNameReference') yourNameReference: TemplateRef <any>;
```

---

FATHER COMPONENT (RECEIVES THE RE-USED COMPONENT)

Add the following code to the '.html' file

```
<ng-template #yourNameReference let-myDataa>
<p> {{myDataa.name}} {{myDataa.lastName}} </p>
</ng-template>
```

---

ANGULAR VERSION: 9/10
DOCUMENTATION: https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

- The documentation does not show the use of ngTemplateOutlet in different components, but it already helps in something.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to use the `@ContentChildren`, [ngTemplateOutlet] can be a variable in the component, you can declare a variable, and give the ng-template you want by `filter` or `find` from the `@ContentChildren QueryList`